# PHP+JSON Display result with no key?

Tags: php, arrays, json

First of all, sorry because my english is bad.

Ive got a problem.
Requesting data from URL in JSON format and got something like:

```
array(1) { ["NICK_HERE"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(123456789) ["name"]=> string(11) "NICK_HERE" ["class"]=> int(538) ["level"]=> int(97) ["online"]=> int(1420061059000) } }
```

And then, I want to display something from there, normally it would be `$x['NICK_HERE']['id']`, but because `NICK_HERE` will be changing, and because i can't use a variable in there, is there a way to bypass this? 
For example something like `$x[0]['id']` ? 
Sort of choose first, no matter whats that?

Appreciate your help!

P.s. Happy New Year!

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "i cant use variable in there" but i would get the keys of the array with `array_keys()` and then use them to iterate over the array (or just get the 'NICK_HERE' one if there will always be just one). When using associative arrays there is no such thing as first or second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice (because I think it is the simplest is to use `current()`, but you can also use `array_column()`...

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c9b058b47c5d3542f94aae4f72c7e98b441c4a6))

```
$array=[
    "NICK_HERE"=>["id"=>123456789,"name"=>"NICK_HERE","class"=>538,"level"=>97,"online"=>1420061059000]
];

echo current($array)['id'];

echo "\n";

echo array_column($array,'id')[0];
```

Output:

```
123456789
123456789
```

These methods assume that the subarray element `id` is guaranteed to exist.  If it might not, you will need to check with `isset()` before trying to access -- to avoid a Notice.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop.
Suppose your array name is $array.

```
foreach($array as $i=>$a)
{
    echo "index: ".$i." id:".$a['id']."<br>";
}
```

Suppose your json string name is `$json`. Then use this way

```
$array=$json_decode($json);  
foreach($array as $i=>$a)
{
    echo "index: ".$i." id:".$a->id."<br>";//here you will get it as object
}
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: do u think this can be effective if i have like thousands of different key data?

Comment: anyway got somehow this to work... $x->id was enough and pretty simple, dunno why earlier forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the first array has one key name you can get the 0th key.

test.php

```
$x = array(
        "NICK_HERE" => array(
                "id" => 123456789,
                "name" => "NICK_HERE",
                "class" => 538,
                "level" => 97,
                "online" => 1420061059000
        )
);

$name = array_keys($x)[0];
echo $x[$name]["id"];

?>
```

output:

```
php test.php
123456789%
```